# How to convert a menu tabs in menu links block?

Tags: 7, theming

It would be very useful to be able to change the "tabs menu" in "menu links" to specific pages and users roles. In order to customize the UI.

I have not found any module for this.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to simply change the menu type from MENU_LOCAL_TASK to MENU CALLBACK, and then simply create a menu item with the path.

Sample Code:
Cherry pick menu tabs and convert:

```
function MYMODULE_NAME_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node/view']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
  $items['node/%node/edit']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
}
```

Convert all at once

```
function MYMODULE_NAME_menu_alter(&$items) {
  foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
    if ($items[$key]['type'] == MENU_LOCAL_TASK) {
      $items[$key]['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But in this way I must reconstruct every path. If I wanted to automatically do it?

Comment: @Daniele I have updated the answer check now if that works for you.